# htaccess skip over parent folder when it doesnt exist

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I currently have www.mysite.com

I only have one subfolder ... www.mysite.com/admin

my current .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /page.php?id=$1 [L]
```

So currently if someone went to **mysite.com/admin** they can access the sub folder and go to the login page.

But if someone types **mysite.com/foo** it changes to **mysite.com/page.php?id=foo** which is exactly what I want.

However, for marketing purposes I need to have the URL display a "parent" folder for certain pages of the site. i.e **mysite.com/parent/foo**

I need to **IGNORE the "parent" part of the url regardless of what I type (Think CATCHALL) as long as an actual folder doesn't exist with that name** and then redirect to **mysite.com/page.php?id=foo**

All my current searches show how to ignore the parent and reroute to index page, but not how to ignore the "parent" and then take the "child" as a variable and append it to a page name with id.

HELP.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(?:[^/]+/)?([^/]+)$ /page.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

The Rule above matches the parent  (non-existent folder) optionally and rewrites the request from :

- example.com/fakefolder/foo

to

- example.com/page.php?id=foo

Comment: This works perfectly... I just need to change my css/js/img paths which is no big deal...

Still trying to get the hang of understanding htaccess...Thank you!!